# What is the hardest tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

As I was laboring over some very attractive unsolved steganography puzzles, I began wondering which tag(s) are the hardest for the community to solve?

I didn't see a breakdown of "time to get an accepted answer" or other objective solvability measure by tag, so forgive me if there are such readily available stats.  I just didn't see them.

As an aside, subjectively many steganography puzzles seem to take a long time to answer, even when [the tag tells you what you need to do](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3032/when-is-the-tag-steganography-too-big-a-hint). Far longer than many complicated ciphers.

Anyway, I was just curious.

Comment: [tag:unsolved-mysteries]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, if you want data [here is a query that returns the average time (in hours) it takes to get an accepted answer by tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/515261/average-time-to-solution-by-tag) (filtering out any tags with less than 10 accepted answers)...

**However** (and I think it's a pretty big *however*), that data is probably largely meaningless, because:

- It [ignores puzzles which have no accepted answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/515284/unsolved-puzzles-by-tag), which in turn ignores entire tags (eg. [unsolved-mysteries](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unsolved-mysteries))
- The number of posts in a majority of tags is probably not enough for statistically significant trends
- There can be a massive range of difficulty, even within a single tag (eg. rot13 vs [solitaire](https://www.schneier.com/academic/solitaire/) both being tagged [cipher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cipher))
- Time to solve is often more a factor of how niche the knowledge/skills required to solve the thing (i.e. the more niche the tag, the less eyeballs looking, the longer it takes)
- Difficulty is often very subjective and relates to the solver's experience/interests (i.e. what's trivial to you may be impossible to me)

Comment: Thanks! For the query and for the insight!